# highlight a word in textarea in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a TextArea control in my ASP.NET page which gets populated with a paragraph containing multiple sentences from the database. After this data gets populated in the TextArea control, I need to search for a few words in them and highlight them in different color. The words that I need to highlight are present inside a table in the database.

My question is : How do I highlight the selected words in a TextArea control using C#?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: is it a must to present the paragraph inside a textarea?
If not, I suggest you to render it inside a label, but just before you do so, do a simple string.replace by every word you have, and replace it with a suitable style
ex: paragraph.Replace("MyWord","<b>MyWord</b>");

Answer (score 0):

The HTML <textarea> tag doesn't contain the ability to add any text formatting. If you want to highlight a portion of your text, then you'll need to display it within a <div>, <span> or some other HTML element.

If you need to make the text editable and still highlight portions of it, then you could use a WYSIWYG HTML editor, such as the [jHtmlArea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com) Free, Open Source jQuery plugin.

Shameless Plug: jHtmlArea is a jQuery plugin I created a while back to fit a need I had for a light weight, easily extensible WYSIWYG HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the DynaCloud jQuery plugin, or CodeMirror. Both provide some functionality for highlighting text.

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

http://codemirror.net/